# Induced representation from subgroup to subgroup

Tags: representation-theory

I wonder why the third of the properties of the induced representation here (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InducedRepresentation.html) holds. Does it follow from the universal property? I could not find the question on stackexchange.

Coming from the definition (3) as in [Facts about induced representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344921/facts-about-induced-representations?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: somehow I was tired and misread the question, i.e. I answered a different one. But hey, the thing I answered to begin with is cool, so let's just leave it there as extra. When $K \le H \le G$ are subgroups,
$$
k[G] \otimes_{k[H]} k[H] \otimes_{k[K]} V = k[G] \otimes_{k[K]} V
$$
gives you the induction formula.

I noticed [they](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InducedRepresentation.html) defined the action incorrectly, which makes it very hard to understand what's going on. The correct definition is written down [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_representation#Analytic) in the topological group and unitary representations case, or in this post in the finite group case over an arbitrary field.

Let $k$ be a field (a priori, it could also be a ring, but I want to keep saying words like "vector bundle"). In this post, I consider a finite group $G$ with subgroup $H$ and a representation $\rho : H \to \mathrm{GL}(W)$. We define a group action on $G \times W$ via $\bar g \cdot (g,w) \overset{def}= (\bar g g,w)$ and the equivalence relation
$$
\forall h \in H, \quad (g,w) \sim (gh, \rho_h^{-1}(w)). 
$$
(This equivalence relation mimics the property of the tensor product $k[G] \otimes_{k[H]} W$ where $gh \otimes w = g \otimes \rho_h(w)$). Denote the equivalence class of $(g,w)$ by $[g,w]$. This equivalence relation is $G$-invariant :
$$
\bar g \cdot (gh,\rho_h^{-1}(w)) = (\bar g gh,\rho_h^{-1}(w)) \sim (\bar gg, w),
$$
so that letting $\mathcal L_W \overset{def}= G \times W / \!\sim$, we obtain an action of $G$ on $\mathcal L_W$ (via the above formula, i.e. $\bar g \cdot [g,w] \overset{def}= [\bar gg,w]$). We also have a projection map of $G$-sets given by $\pi : \mathcal L_W \to G/H$ defined by $\pi([g,w]) \overset{def}= gH$. This turns $\mathcal L_W$ into a vector bundle (operations performed pointwise) over $G/H$ with fiber $W$ since choosing a system of left coset representatives $\{r_1,\cdots,r_{|G|/|H|}\}$,  we can produce an isomorphism $\mathcal L_W \simeq G/H \times W$ of vector bundles over $G/H$ via $[r_i,w] \mapsto (r_i,w)$. However, this is not convenient to study the action of $G$ on $\mathcal L_W$.

Let $\Gamma(G/H,\mathcal L_W)$ denote the space of sections of this vector bundle, namely the set of functions $s : G/H \to \mathcal L_W$ written $s(gH) = [g,s_g]$ where $s_g \in W$ (the sections are not required to be maps of $G$-sets). Since $[g,s_g] = [gh,\rho_h^{-1}s_g]$, the section $s \in \Gamma(G/H,\mathcal L_W)$ corresponds to a function $\bar s : G \to W$ satisfying $\bar s_{gh} = \rho_h^{-1} \bar s_g$. The correspondence $s \mapsto \bar s$ is $k$-linear and we will put an action of $G$ on both $\Gamma(G/H, \mathcal L_W)$ and
$$
\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W) \overset{def}= \{ \bar s : G \to W \mid \forall h \in H, \, g \in G, \quad \bar s_{gh} = \rho_h^{-1} \bar s_g\}
$$
which makes this correspondence $k[G]$-linear.

Consider the map $\Gamma(G/H,\mathcal L_W) \to k[G] \otimes_{k[H]}W$ defined by 
$$
\left( s : G/H \to \mathcal L_W, s(gH) = [g,s_g] \right) \mapsto \sum_{g \in G} g \otimes s_g. 
$$
In the reverse direction, for a function $s : G \to W$, set
$$
\widehat s : G \to W, \quad \widehat s(g) = \frac 1{|H|} \sum_{h \in H} \rho_h(s(gh)).
$$
Note that $\widehat s$ satisfies the property $\rho_h(\widehat s(gh)) = \widehat s(g)$ for all $h \in H$, hence $\widehat s \in \mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W)$. We can re-write an arbitrary element of $k[G] \otimes_{k[H]} W$ as
$$
\sum_{g \in G} g \otimes s_g = \sum_{i=1}^{|G:H|} \sum_{h \in H} r_i h \otimes s_{r_ih} = \sum_{i=1}^{|G:H|} r_i \otimes \left( \sum_{h \in H} \rho_h(s_{r_ih}) \right) = |H| \sum_{i=1}^{|G:H|} r_i \otimes \widehat s(r_i). \\
\sum_{h \in H} \sum_{i=1}^{|G:H|} r_i \otimes \rho_h(\widehat s(r_ih)) = \sum_{h \in H} \sum_{i=1}^{|G:H|} r_ih \otimes \widehat s(r_ih) 
=\sum_{g \in G} g \otimes \widehat s(g). 
$$
Define the inverse map $k[G] \otimes_{k[H]}W \to \Gamma(G/H,\mathcal L_W)$ by : 
$$
\sum_{g \in G} g \otimes s_g \mapsto \left( gH \mapsto [g, \widehat s(g)] \right).
$$
This is easily seen to be a $k$-linear isomorphism, hence there is a unique choice of $k[G]$-module structure on $\Gamma(G/H,\mathcal L_W)$ which makes this a $k[G]$-linear isomorphism (i.e. "transport de structure"), namely the one given by the natural action of $G$ on $\mathcal L_W$ :
$$
\bar g \cdot (gH \mapsto [g,s_g]) \overset{def}=(gH \mapsto [g,s_{\bar g^{-1}g}]) = (gH \mapsto [\bar g g, s_g]).  
$$
What is nice about this action is that any section $s : G/H \to \mathcal L_W$ is automatically a map of $G$-sets. It also gives $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W)$ a $k[G]$-module structure via 
$$
(s : G \to W) \mapsto (\bar g \cdot s : G \to W, \quad g \mapsto s(\bar  g^{-1}g)).
$$
All these correspondences are natural $k[G]$-linear isomorphisms, so I hope you understand the situation better!

Hope that helps,

Comment: I think the OP meant the third property listed (transitivity) rather than why the third definition was the same as the others.

Comment: @Tobias Klidetoft : Oh dear. XD well I guess a short answer to his question is "Yes."